# psycopg2 escape character issue

Tags: postgresql, escaping, psycopg2

I am trying to write a python script to periodically use \COPY TO to export a select statement to a CSV file.

The query is

```
postgres=# \copy (select * from mytable where temp>32.5) to ...
```

This command works in psql command line.
But in my script it gives this error, presumably to do with escape characters in strings:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 2:         \copy (select * 
                ^
```

I have tried the obvious '//' in my python code to no avail. It appears escaping the forward slash or not escaping the forward slash produce identical errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\copy` is a `psql` command only. Use Psycopg's [`copy_expert cursor method`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert):

```
cursor.copy_expert (
    'copy (select * from mytable where temp>32.5) to stdout'
    '\path\to\file.csv'
),
```